# order a list of datarow in ascending acording to a specified column

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have DataRow[] selected  from DataTable .

I need to order this list in ascending according to a specified column field .

how can i do that?

```
 DataRow[] Stations = Distances.Select("Pointid='" + Pointid + "' and Distance<='" + SearchRadius + "'");
```

and i need to sort it in ascending according distance field

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Sorted DataRows like:

```
int Pointid = 1;
double SearchRadius = 0.5d;

DataRow[] Stations = Distances.AsEnumerable()
                     .Where(r => r.Field<int>("Pointid") == Pointid &&
                            r.Field<double>("Distance") <= SearchRadius)
                    .OrderBy(r => r.Field<double>("Distance"))
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: but,Im select this list acorrding to condition : DataRow[] Stations = Distances.Select("Pointid='" + Pointid + "' and Distance<='" + SearchRadius + "'");  and i need to sort it in ascending according distance field

Comment: @Enas, I have modified answer according to your requirement, I am assuming that `Pointid` is of type `int` and `Distance` is of type `double`. Replace those according to your requirement and you should get your rows ordered in nearest distance first.